# ExtJs: How to show viewmodel after store load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need that my viewmodel MainModel appears after store 'OrgStore' load.

Now I have next App.js:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'BillWebApp',

    extend: 'BillWebApp.Application',
    stores: ['OrgStore'],
    requires: [
        'BillWebApp.view.main.Main'
    ],
    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.getStore('OrgStore');
        store.on('load', function() {
            BillWebApp.getApplication().setMainView('main.Main');
        });
    },
...
```

OrgStore:

```
Ext.define('BillWebApp.store.OrgStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias  : 'store.orgstore',
    storeId: 'OrgStore',
    model: 'BillWebApp.model.Org',
    config:{
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true
    },
    proxy: {
        autoSave: false,
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create  : '',
            read    : '/base/getOrgAll',
            update  : '',
            destroy : ''
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }, listeners: {
        load: function() {
            console.log("OrgStore loaded!");
        }
    }
});
```

MainModel:

```
Ext.define('BillWebApp.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    data: {
        name: 'BillWebApp',
    },

    stores: {
        orgstore: {
            type: 'orgstore'
        }
    }

});
```

Why I in log window see message "OrgStore loaded!" twice?
One after 'OrgStore' loaded, and next one after MainModel started?

I think I invoke two instances of 'OrgStore'....
How can I change my code to show MainModel after store fully load?

Comment: Set autoload to false

Comment: It doesn't help - line BillWebApp.getApplication().setMainView('main.Main') will not execute

Comment: You're creating 2 instances of the store. #1 `stores: ['OrgStore'],` #2 In your viewmodel stores config.

Comment: Invoke store.load() in application launch.